# Segmentation fault in Python after Ubuntu update

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, mysql-python, ubuntu-14.04

I recently apt-get updated my Ubuntu 14.04 server. Now I am getting `Segmentation fault` when I try to connect to a MySQL db in Python using MySQLdb. I can connect to the database from other sources and incorrect credentials throws the expected error. This python script also works from other machines (OSX).

```
import MySQLdb
MySQLdb.connect(host = 'host', user = 'user', passwd = 'password', db = 'db')
```

Example code and output

```
$ python test.py
Segmentation fault
```

$ python --version --> Python 2.7.6

I have purge removed python and reinstalled and the error remains. Does anyone have any suggestions for trouble shooting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rebuild `MySQLdb` since it was previously compiled on a previous version of the system (glic, etc are different now).

A simple `pip install --force MySQLdb` should fix you up.